# Text View with two button at bottom

Tags: android, layout

I need simple text view with bottom two buttons, in **XML** 
Like this

[image]

I have tried to work with two button at bottom side with relative view , but could not success and not able to add text view can any one have any idea , please

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far?

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
    android:text="ABC"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="button2" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

   <TextView 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Text"/>


     <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:text="button1" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:text="button2" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Don't do this. Our good friends at Google took the time to create a `RelativeLayout` so you don't have to do this